# How can I add multiple of lines text (a paragraph) to an svg?

Tags: svg

I want to add multiple lines of text to an svg, which would be contained within the svg (does not overflow). How can I do that?

I knew that the `text` tag is used in svg, but I discovered that it's single lined. Then, when I give it `textLength` (so that it would contained in specific svg), its words overlap with each other. How can I put multiple lines of text which would adjust in svg tag? The code I tried is below:

```html
<svg width="200" height="60" style="border: 1px solid black;">
  <text x="10" y="30" textLength="180" style="font-size: 30px;">The paragraph here</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work. SVG has no mechanism for breaking lines.

That said, you would be able to encapsulate a html `<p>` tag as a `foreignObject`:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="21cm" height="29.7cm" style="border:1px solid black;">
  <foreignObject x="6.4cm" y="3.6cm" width="10cm" height="10cm">
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
       style="font-size:48px;">The paragraph here</p>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Please note that the namespace declarations **must** be given, and you need to write valid XHML for this to work.

In addition, `foreignObject` is part of the SVG context, so a `width` and `height` need to be set, otherwise it will have no inherent size.

Comment: IE11 dont support foreignObject